# use on premise gateway to connect to local file system. gateway doesnt appears in creating connection

Tags: power-automate, onpremises-gateway

I installed On Premise Gateway with sufficient right to access the local file system / network.
when create a new connection no gateway appears. keep asking to install gateway.
[see print screen creating new connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hGy5.png)

have I missed some additional settings so I can select the gateway?

Answer (score 0):

1. Confirm you have installed the "Standard mode gateway" and not "Personal mode gateway".

You should see this:
[image]

2. Confirm your gateway is installed in the same region as your Power Automate environment.

Comment: Hi Sam it is the standard mode gateway. could the gateway service account be the problem?

Comment: Great, now see No. 2 above, is it installed in the same region?

Comment: Yes it's West Europe